# Defining custom managed service fails

Tags: service, managed, intershop

We are trying to develop custom Intershop Managed Service following cookbook: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2329T4
But when trying to enable service in Operations for our Organization, it is not listed there and there is a warning log message:

```
WARN  localhost ES1 appserver0 [Test-Site]  com.intershop.component.service.internal.service.ORMServiceConfigurationBORepositoryImpl [] [Storefront] [8ocH1vmRUp4E1qKOZQQC5FFRtQai9r4QV6dAV1yx] [oBlLAFsfl5kFMqjA-0-00] "oBlLAFsfl5kFMqjA-0-00" Can't load implementation for service definition: cartridge='service_esb', service definition id='ESBServiceDefinition'.
```

Here is services.compoment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010">
  <!-- Adapter interface -->
  <contract name="ESBService" class="com.test.service.capi.ESBService" />

  <!-- ServiceDefintion implementation -->
  <implementation name="ESBServiceDefinitionImpl" class="com.test.service.internal.ESBServiceDefinition" implements="ServiceDefinition" />

  <!-- ServiceDefintion instance that has already one adapter added -->
  <instance name="ESBServiceDefinition" with="ESBServiceDefinitionImpl" />

  <!-- Registering the ServiceDefintion instance to the (global) ServiceDefinitionRegistry -->
  <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinition" of="serviceDefinitionRegistry">
    <instance with="ServiceDefinitionRegistry.Entry">
      <fulfill requirement="cartridgeID" value="service_esb" />
      <fulfill requirement="groupID" value="service.group.name.test" />
      <fulfill requirement="parameterGroupID" value="ESBParameters" />
      <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinitionID" value="esbService" />
      <fulfill requirement="localizationKeyForName" value="service.definition.name.esbService" />
      <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinition" with="ESBServiceDefinition" />
      <fulfill requirement="ChainElementID" value="LogHandler" />
      <fulfill requirement="ChainElementID" value="MonitorHandler" />
    </instance>
  </fulfill>
</components>
```

All required classes (AdapterInterface, Adapter, ExecutorService, ServiceDefinition - extending AbstractServiceDefinition) are implemented and compiled successfully. Does anybody knows why Intershop can't load implementation?

Also, in Intershop Studio in component editor following error is displayed when services.component is opened:

```
With 'Implementation - ESBServiceDefinitionImpl (unresolved)' cannot be resolved
```

But when clicking CTRL+left mouse button on "ESBServiceDefinitionImpl" implementation is found and

```
<implementation name="ESBServiceDefinitionImpl" class="com.test.service.internal.ESBServiceDefinition" implements="ServiceDefinition" />
```

is highlighted.

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs? Stop the server and clear the logs (error & warn) and start it up again.

Comment: No, nothing else. Just above warning when calling pipeline: ViewChannelServiceList-Dispatch to list all available service in BO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it was typo :) I named folder with service.component "component", and not "components".
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: ah good to hear. Very often when nothing makes sense, it is something small like this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ServiceDefinitionID does not match:

esbService vs. ESBServiceDefinition

Comment: Thanks, tried that. But as I understand from here: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2329T4#Cookbook-ManagedServiceFramework-Recipe:CreateaServiceDefinitionHowtoCreateaServiceDefinition 

serviceDefinitionID is not the same as serviceDefinition:
    serviceDefinitionID - myService - A ServiceDefinition is uniquely defined by cartridgeID and serviceDefinitionID.
    serviceDefinition - MyDefinition - Refers to the MyDefinition instance previously defined in the component configuration file

Comment: One question Nils, is service.compoment file (in custom service_esb cartridge) automatically scanned for available services by server startup? Or how discovery of available services works?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following component settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010" scope="global">
  <!-- Adapter interface -->
  <contract name="ESBService" class="com.test.service.capi.ESBService" />

  <!-- ServiceDefintion implementation -->
  <implementation name="com.test.service.internal.ESBServiceDefinition" class="com.test.service.internal.ESBServiceDefinition" implements="ServiceDefinition" />

  <!-- Registering the ServiceDefintion instance to the (global) ServiceDefinitionRegistry -->
  <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinition" of="serviceDefinitionRegistry">
    <instance with="ServiceDefinitionRegistry.Entry">
      <fulfill requirement="cartridgeID" value="service_esb" />
      <fulfill requirement="groupID" value="service.group.name.test" />
      <fulfill requirement="parameterGroupID" value="ESBParameters" />
      <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinitionID" value="esbService" />
      <fulfill requirement="localizationKeyForName" value="service.definition.name.esbService" />
      <fulfill requirement="serviceDefinition">
        <instance with="com.test.service.internal.ESBServiceDefinition" />
      </fulfill>
      <fulfill requirement="ChainElementID" value="LogHandler" />
      <fulfill requirement="ChainElementID" value="MonitorHandler" />
    </instance>
  </fulfill>
</components>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I'm adding service via DBInit: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2329T4#Cookbook-ManagedServiceFramework-Recipe:AddanAdapterDuringDBInitHowtoAddanAdapterDuringDBInit

Comment: Did u also try to add it manually? If u can add it manually first we can look at the dbinit preparer later.

Comment: I can't add it manually because there is no ESBService listed under services tab under Sales Organizations -> https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2329T4#Cookbook-ManagedServiceFramework-Recipe:EnabletheServiceEnabletheService

Comment: try using one of a standard groupid. <fulfill requirement="groupID" value="service.group.name.Order_Export_Services" />. Should then be listed under Order Export Services. There must be a configuration bug somewhere

Comment: No, when opening Order Export Services group only "Local XML File Order Export" is displayed :(

Comment: Maybe component framework doesn't even load my services.componet? Is there any way I could check?

Comment: When debugging GetServiceDefinitions, I can see that ServiceDefinitionRegistry don't have my service registered. This is probably the issue, but why is that? I can see that my cartridge 'service_esb' that has service.component under staticfiles/cartridge/component is loaded in SMC for intershop.SLDSystem application.

Comment: yeah, your service is not loading and usually the log files at startup will give you some clue why it didn't load a component. I'm also quite puzzled. Did you look at the logs file under eserver/server/local/log/ and eserver/server/share/system/log. You can also enable the debug logging in smc to maybe give some clue. Also is it possible to publish the cartridge to github? So i can try it on my machine.

Comment: I'm currently trying to import https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Deliver/DOC/2329T4/sample_service_cartridge_source.zip cartridge and see if that service is registered. Will update you with results. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173112/discussion-between-willem-evertse-and-goran-petanjek).

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but did you try to redeploy the server after creating the custom managed service?

1. Stop the server.
2. Run `gradlew deployServer`
3. Start the server

Comment: Yes, tried that also. Manually check that cartridge is deployed under server directory and loaded in SMC.